# ExactTarget: Where is the master list for SOAP Faults?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

Currently receiving `faultstring: 'Account Disabled'` but that is not listed in the soap faults list: http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/soap_faults/

Is there a larger list of faults and explanations?

Comment: Were you ever able to determine what was causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is the list, and it is not complete.  I would suggest that you first try and log into the ET application with your current credentials.  Assuming you have administrator rights, verify that this user has API rights, and if not, assign them and try again.

If you are unable to make this work, give support a call.

Hope this helps.